# Running into misbehaviour during hashing the password field

Tags: sql-server

I want to store hashed passwords in my database and I have used the following code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE AddUser
@name NVARCHAR(MAX),
@password NVARCHAR(MAX),
@responseMessage NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
        INSERT INTO [User] (Username, PasswordHashed)
        VALUES (@name, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @password));
END
```

Current instance of my table has the following state (The User's password is *hi*):
[image]

For validating users I'm using the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [User]
WHERE [User].Username = 'Bamdad' AND [User].PasswordHashed = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'hi');
```

But the result is `0`. Why doesn't the latter code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying your password `'hi'` as `varchar` but procedure requires an `nvarchar`. So the `varchar` gets promoted to `nvarchar` with an extra byte, hence the difference in encryption.